# Unable to use Mathml in Ionic2

Tags: ionic2, mathjax

I want to use Mathml inside Ionic2, I have added mathjax cdn in the index.html, and added *CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA* in app.module.ts

`<script type="text/javascript" async  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=MML_CHTML"></script>`

in @NgModule i use

```
import { NgModule,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HelloIonicPage } from '../pages/hello-ionic/hello-ionic';
import { ItemDetailsPage } from '../pages/item-details/item-details';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';
import {MathmlComponent} from '../components/mathml-component/mathml-component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HelloIonicPage,
    ItemDetailsPage,
    ListPage,
    MathmlComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HelloIonicPage,
    ItemDetailsPage,
    ListPage
  ],
  providers: [],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My mathml-component.ts is

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector:'mathml-component',
  template:`
  <math>
    <mstyle displaystyle="true">
      <mover>
        <mrow>
          <mi>f</mi>
        </mrow>
        <mo>&#x2192;</mo>
      </mover>
    </mstyle>
  </math>
  `
})

export class MathmlComponent{


  constructor(){
    console.log('done')
  }
}
```

**But I am getting error**

```
polyfills.js:3 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
':math:mi' is not a known element:
1. If ':math:mi' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If ':math:mi' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
      <mover>
        <mrow>
          [ERROR ->]<mi>f</mi>
        </mrow>
        <mo>&#x2192;</mo>
"): MathmlComponent@5:10
':math:mrow' is not a known element:
```

Plz help.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Instead of using MathMl I use Tex/Latex in MAthjax.